# how to make my laptop run on minimum resources?

Tags: resources, resource-monitor, resource-usage, resource-management

I download large files so I want to leave the laptop on for 3 or 4 days.  I guess I should reduce the resources consumption so it doesn't heat up much.  How can I do that? Also is this logic right or wrong?

Another question, how can I find out which graphics card is running in a particular game when it's running? (Nvidia or Intel)

And another, how so I check if my pc is running on it's full resources while a game is running?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Re coolness
A)if the laptop fans are working and it's on a good surface e.g. not a carpet.. but wood or glass,  then it shouldn't heat up B)you can get a laptop cooler.

Re graphics card, there are loads of computer auditing software. Look up computer audit freeware. Belarc is one many people use.

Re checking resources used. You could bring up task manager e.g. ctrl shift escape, then click performance, and see the RAM usage and CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Re Q1: Actually there's not much you can do. In general, current hardware (processor, chipset) will slow down when there's nothing to do. If you don't block ventilation, you should be fine. Switch off any external hardware if there is (e.g. screen).

Re Q3: Depends on OS. On Windows you can use task manager or resource monitor.